# Why can I put an ifstream file in an if condition?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I am trying to check if the file opened successfully. And I found this method to open files to be read:

```
char path[]="data/configuration.txt";
std::ifstream configFile(path, std::ifstream::in);
if(configFile) {
  std::cout<<"Successfully opened file: "<<path<<std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout<<"Error, Could not open file: "<<path<<std::endl;
}
```

The question is what exactly does `if` checks for ?

Because I also found the following method of checking if a file is open:

```
char path[]="data/configuration.txt";
std::ifstream configFile;
configFile.open(path, std::ifstream::in);
if(configFile.is_open()) {
  std::cout<<"Successfully opened file: "<<path<<std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout<<"Error, Could not open file: "<<path<<std::endl;
}
```

I do have some other questions. For example, what is the difference between the two methods of opening the file ? Also, what would be the difference in the two `if` conditions ?

I think these are similar methods that end up with the same result, because I can use `std::ifstream` methods, like `is_open` with both opening methods:

```
std::ifstream configFile(path, std::ifstream::in);
configFile.open(path, std::ifstream::in);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::ifstream` could *[contextually convert to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions)* via [`std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which is inherited from `std::basic_ios`.

> Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

Note that it performs different check with [`std::basic_ifstream<CharT,Traits>::is_open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open).

> Checks if the file stream has an associated file. Effectively calls `rdbuf()->is_open()`.

Comment: And what are the cases in which those two are used ? What is "better" to check if the file opened ? And what is the one best used to avoid data race condition ?

Comment: from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ it says that the ultimate base class is `ios_base`. Can you explain how `ifstream` inherits from `basic_ios`

Comment: @bleah1 `operator bool` checks whether the stream has errors or not; then I think you want `is_open`.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje You might want to check the inheritance diagram [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

Comment: @songyuanyao I also thought that `is_open()` is better suited for my case. But I've wanted to understand what's behind them

Comment: @bleah1 They're just two different methods, which one should be used depends on your intent.

Comment: @songyuanyao What about the opening methods: `std::ifstream configFile(path, std::ifstream::in);` and `configFile.open(path, std::ifstream::in);` ? Are they different ? How ?

Comment: @bleah1 According to the document [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open), the effect is same.